# Dynamically Add Files to Request Post

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using the node module  [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms)

I need to attached several files to the form post. I have the filenames that I need to attach in the following format:

```
var images = "images1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg"
```

I'm not sure how to include them into the form post. According to the docs, you declare the form data like:

```
var formData = {

  attachments: [
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/image1.jpg'),
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/image2.jpg'),
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/image3.jpg'),
  ],
};
```

But how do I loop through the content of "images" and use "fs.createReadStream" to dynamically add the images to the form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array from your images

```
images = images.split(',');
```

Then attach each image

```
var formData = { attachments: []}

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    formData.attachments.push(fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + images[i]));
}
```